# Spring data mongo - Get sum of array of object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

I have the following document:

```
{
   pmv: {
        budgets: [
           {
              amount: 10
           },
           {   
              amount: 20
           }
         ]
     }
}
```

and I need to sum the `amount` field from every object in `budgets`. But it's also possible that the `budget` object doesn't exist so I need to check that.

How could I do this? I've seen many questions but with projections, I just need a integer number which in this case would be 30.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1 FOR PUNIT**

This is the code I tried but its giving me and empty aray

```
AggregationOperation filter = match(Criteria.where("pmv.budgets").exists(true).not().size(0));
            AggregationOperation unwind = unwind("pmv.budgets");
            AggregationOperation sum = group().sum("budgets").as("amount");

            Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filter, unwind, sum);

            mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"Iniciativas",String.class);

            AggregationResults<String> aggregationa = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"Iniciativas",String.class);

            List<String> results = aggregationa.getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation pipeline

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.aggregate([
  {"pmv.budgets":{$exists:true,$not:{$size:0}}},
  {$unwind:"$pmv.budgets"},
  {amount:{$sum:"$pmv.budgets"}}
]);
```

This pipeline contains three queries:

1. get document having non-null and non-empty budgets
2. `$unwind` basically open the array and create one document for each array element. e.g. if one document of budgets has 3 elements then it will create 3 document and fill budgets property from each of the array element. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
3. sum all the budgets property using `$sum` operator

You can read more about aggregation pipeline [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

EDIT: as per comments, adding code for java as well.

```
AggregationOperation filter = match(Criteria.where("pmv.budgets").exists(true).not().size(0));
AggregationOperation unwind = unwind("pmv.budgets");
AggregationOperation sum = group().sum("pmv.budgets").as("amount");

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filter, unwind, sum);

mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,COLLECTION_NAME,Output.class);
```

You can do this in more inline way as well but I wrote it like this so that it will be easy to understand.

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: I know how it's in Mongo but idk how to translate it into java

Comment: hi @Wrong, added java code as well. let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I am really sorry @PunitTiwan, I forgot to mention that the budget object is inside another object. I've edited my questions with your code and what I tried but success.

Comment: @Wrong I think you will have to use "pmv.budgets" instead of "budgets" in ```sum``` operator or give the projected name as "budgets" in ```unwind```

Comment: I had to put 'pmv' in the match criteria (it might not exists but budgets always exist if pmv exists), then $budgets in the unwind and then 'budgets' in the sum. I'll accept your answer but modify that forr future readers, please :)

Comment: ah!! yeah, that had to be done if it goes inside another object. modified my answer as well :)